# Can tensorflow modify graph structure every train step?

Tags: python-2.7, tensorflow, deep-learning

I need to construct my graph structrue according to current input data.

It means I may need to use different graph structure at every train step.

But tensorflow only construct graph once and use it till the end.

So,  is there a solution for this problem?

simple code like this:

```
import tensorflow as tf

data = [[1, 2, 3],
        [3, 2, 1]]
index = 0


def feed_dict():
    return data[index]

with tf.Session() as sess:
    embedding = tf.constant([[1, 1, 1],
                             [2, 2, 2],
                             [3, 3, 3],
                             [4, 4, 4]])

    words = tf.placeholder(tf.int32, [3])
    sess.run(tf.initialize_all_variables())
    embed = tf.nn.embedding_lookup(embedding, words)
    word_list = tf.unpack(embed)
    result = None
    if tf.less(tf.reduce_sum(word_list[0]), tf.reduce_sum(word_list[1])).eval(feed_dict={words: feed_dict()}):
        result = word_list[0] * word_list[1] + word_list[2]
    else:
        result = word_list[0] + word_list[1] * word_list[2]

    for i in xrange(2):
        print sess.run(result, feed_dict={words: feed_dict()})
        index += 1
```

I wish it can print :

```
[10, 10, 10]

[10, 10, 10]
```

but  I get:

```
[10, 10, 10]

[14, 14, 14]
```

It tells that the second run use the same graph as the first.

Thank you for your reading !   I'll appreciate every help.

Comment: I am an Chinese student and this is my first question.  So, I hope I made my description  clear and right. if not, please let my know. Thanks !

Comment: You can modify graph structure at every step. There's a performance penalty, perhaps additional 20-100ms per run call, depending on size of your graph

Comment: Thanks!  But how can I make that?  I mean, what will the code look like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These are expected results.

First, you evaluate `tf.less`, so the `result` will **always** be `result = world_list[0] * word_list[1] + word_list[2]`.

Note that the embedding is zero-based, so in the first case, you get `2 * 3 + 4 = 10`, and in the second `4 * 3 + 2 = 14`, as printed.

If you mean to evaluate `tf.less` at runtime, use `tf.cond`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! It should work!  I'll try this  as soon as possible.